# How to send a requst in each angular route

Tags: angular

I want to send a request for check user authentication.

My request :

```
'http://example.com/api/user/signin/check?token=' + token
```

I send a request inside **`ngOnInit()`** at  **`app.component.ts`** and its work correctly .

> the problem is **`app.component.ts`** send my request only once  i need
>   to send this request to server in each route change

Comment: What if the token becomes invalid between the moment you send the request and the moment you navigate to the route? Don't spam your server with useless continuous checks like that. Check the token once, and if it happens to become invalid, react to the error sent back by the server by showing an error message or navigating to the login page.

Comment: @JBNizet I need to check if user logged for example show the profile page..how can i check ? 
The only way is set a localStorage session i guess ... 
This is not a safe way .. What can i do ?

Comment: Why is it not a safe way? The token should be sent as part of each *real* request to the server, and the server should verify it every time. Security happens on the server, not on the client. On the client, just checking that you have a token should be sufficient.

Comment: @JBNizet So you mean I do not need `Routing guards`  ?
and must send the token in each request .. even for example (take the articles at main page ?)  never mind what the request is  just send the token if exist and check that .    
Is that right ?

Comment: @Ben_Rmb correct me if I understand you wrong. Do you want to check if user session is still valid/ logged on server side with each rout activate.

Comment: @MaihanNijat i want to check if user logged do something and if has permission do else and at last if not logged do something else. in each page (for example if you are admin show you the admin btn or if you have no permission just hide the login btn ,, it is what i want)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Anglar [Routing guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) with the [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) guard interface.

```
@Injectable()
export class CheckAuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(/* Inject whatever you want here */) {}

  public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree {
    // Make request and return if you are authenticated or not.
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'home/',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [CheckAuthenticationGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'otherRoute',
        component: OtherComponent,
        canActivate: [CheckAuthenticationGuard]
      },
      ...
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    ...,
    CheckAuthenticationGuard 
  ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Each time you will navigate to one of your defined routes, it will execute the `CheckAuthenticationGuard` and if your `canActivate` method returns `true`, it will activate your route, otherwise, it will give you an error.